# Fading in menu items on load (with delay)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I was wondering how to make the individual menu items fade in with delay on page load.

I would like them to fade in not in a chronological order, so let's say first to appear would be `#item 3`, then `#item 1`, then `#item 5` and so on...

How would such a `jQuery` or `JavaScript` code look and where in the code would I need to paste it?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Do you wanna load them when they come into view or just delay and load even when the user is not doing anything?

Comment: yes, I would like them to show up one by one just when I open the page (even when user is not doing anything )

Comment: yes, thanks! but they are appearing chronologically one by one , what if i want menu item 3 appear first ? Also this code is in 3 pieces - where do i paste it in my code? sorry but I am a total beginner only familiar with html a bit!

Comment: Check I have added the full code.

Comment: Thanks, I clicked a thick button (tho it doesn't show publicly). I pasted this code and it kind of works but menu items still  show in chronological order. What I want for the 6 items that I have in the menu is to fade in not in a regular sequence, but something like this 4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 6. I also want to make the fades in overlap, so rather than say having item 5 go right after item 1 has fully faded in, I would like each item to start fading in half-way through the previous item's fade in. So all six items should reveal in a kind of irregular and overlapping fade in.

Comment: Check this: **http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job. Basically give the elements that you want to fadeIn a class of hidden, or any other class name that you can target. You then set the display of that class to "none". Using jQuery you target each item that you want to fadeIn by its ID and you set a desired delay() before that item will be fadedIn using the fadeIn() function.

So in this example #item2 will fadeIn after 1500ms, #item3 after 2500ms and #item1 after 4000ms.

Hope this helps!

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fade In</title>
    
        <style type="text/css">
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="item1" class="hidden">First</li>
                <li id="item2" class="hidden">Second</li>
                <li id="item3" class="hidden">Third</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#item1').delay(4000).fadeIn('slow')
                $('#item3').delay(2500).fadeIn('slow')
                $('#item2').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow')
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks , it looks good , however , I incorporated this in my code and all the menu  items disappear for good instead of fading ... Any ideas what's wrong? :/

Comment: Can you please post the script you are running?

Comment: <nav>
     <ul>
       <li id="item1" class="hidden" ><a href="Gallery/Ruins/index.html">ruins</a></li>
       <li id="item2" class="hidden"><a href="Gallery/Synagogues/index.html" >synagogues</a></li>
       <li id="item3" class="hidden"><a href="Gallery/Tombstones/index.html" >tombstones</a></li>
       <li id="item4" class="hidden" ><a href="Gallery/Monochrome/index.html" >monochrome</a></li>
       <li id="item5" class="hidden"><a href="Gallery/Medley/index.html" >medley</a></li>
       <li id="item6" class="hidden" ><a href="About.html" >about </a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#item1').delay(4000).fadeIn('slow')
                $('#item3').delay(2500).fadeIn('slow')
                $('#item2').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow')
    $('#item4').delay(5000).fadeIn('slow')
    $('#item6').delay(3500).fadeIn('slow')
    $('#item5').delay(4500).fadeIn('slow')
            })
        </script>

Comment: I tried your syntax and it worked, except that I added commas at the end of every line like so: 
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#item1').delay(4000).fadeIn('slow');` <-- Notice the semi-column.

Here is the example in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/97kdg8ha/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` and put it into a closure and work.

```js
$(function () {
  var currentTime = 0;
  $("#item1, #item2, #item3")
    .hide()
    .each(function () {
    (function (which, currentTime) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        which.fadeIn(100);
      }, currentTime);
    })($(this), currentTime);
    currentTime += 2500;
  });
});
```

```css
div {background: #ccf; margin: 10px; line-height: 100px; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div id="item1">This is menu 1.</div>
<div id="item2">This is menu 2.</div>
<div id="item3">This is menu 3.</div>
```

**Full Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var currentTime = 0;
        $("#item3, #item1, #item2")
          .hide()
          .each(function () {
          (function (which, currentTime) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              which.fadeIn(100);
            }, currentTime);
          })($(this), currentTime);
          currentTime += 2500;
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      div {background: #ccf; margin: 10px; line-height: 100px; text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <title>My Menus</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="item1">This is menu 1.</div>
    <div id="item2">This is menu 2.</div>
    <div id="item3">This is menu 3.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is applied to the items in order no matter their order in selector. I guess jquery does pattern matching and item1 is matched before item2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

### This can be achieved by following these steps:

**1. Set the "display" property of the elements to "none" in CSS**

**2. Put your code in** "$(document).ready(function(){ **here** })" **after including the jQuery library**

**3. Set the** delay(**value**) **to the elements as needed for the order you want to show the elements**

**4. Call the fade function or any other effect or function for the elements**

You can make the elements appear in any order you want, you just need to set the delay(**value**) accordingly. The later you want the elements to appear, the higher should you set this value.

In this example the elements appear in chronological order, just change the delay(**value**) to suit your needs. You can select the elements according to your needs. For example, here ID isn't used to select the elements, but can be used as well. This method works great too!

Remember to include the jQuery library first!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            li {
            display: none
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("li:nth-child(1)").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(2)").delay("1000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(3)").delay("2000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(4)").delay("3000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(5)").delay("4000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(6)").delay("5000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(7)").delay("6000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(8)").delay("7000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(9)").delay("8000").fadeIn();
            $("li:nth-child(10)").delay("9000").fadeIn();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>First</li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Fourth</li>
            <li>Fifth</li>
            <li>Sixth</li>
            <li>Seventh</li>
            <li>Eighth</li>
            <li>Ninth</li>
            <li>Tenth</li>

        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a list like this of unknown number of items

```
<div class="fadein-delay">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  ...
</div>
```

you will a more modular script

```
$(function () {
  $(".fadein-delay > div").each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).text());
      $(this).delay(300*index).fadeIn(600);
  });
});
```

and css that hides all items initially

```
.fadein-delay > div {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is a working example https://codepen.io/giorgosk/pen/aVpXad